# Printing pyramid of numbers

Tags: java

I have homework to make a triangle that looks like this:

```
    1
   1 2
  1 2 3
 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

I have been able to create almost half the triangle with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I have been unable to figure out how to mirror the other half of the triangle with my code to look like the triangle above. The instructor hinted that using the for loop with the tab return \t is the way to do this.

Comment: You need another loop to create the spaces. A tab would be too much.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Maroun's answer but simpler

```
int size = 6;
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < size; j++)
        System.out.print(" ");
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

or

```
int size = 6;
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    for (int j = i - size + 1; j <= i; j++)
        System.out.print((j > 0 ? j : "") + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

prints

```
     1 
    1 2 
   1 2 3 
  1 2 3 4 
 1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
int x = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
   for(int k = x; k < 4; k++) {
      System.out.print(" ");  
   }
   x++; //less spaces will be printed in the next iteration
   for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      System.out.print(j + " ");
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

I wrote another loop that begins with 4 spaces and then the amount of spaces is reduced.

---

Output:

```
    1
   1 2
  1 2 3
 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Tip: Always open `{` for your loops and conditions, even for one operation, this might prevent bugs.